# Magento 2 page structure is destroyed

Tags: magento2, page

[image]

Am shift from **window** to **Ubuntu 18.04** I run clean, flush, upgrade and also deploy commands But page layout still destroy.
When I face this issue in the window then just run **deploy** command, page structure would right. But in Ubuntu it still destroys 
Why ? which command I run to fix the layout.

Comment: check the console for the erros

Comment: Enable mode rewrite at apache if you using apache as webserver

Comment: `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

`sudo systemctl restart apache2`

Enable rewrite mod and restart apache But still page layout not correct

Comment: to i check the console 8 to 10 files has status 404 not found.
how fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to debug this issue :
1 - Check if symlinks are configured properly it can be issue due to symlink. ( to check try to access :

`http://localhost/domain.com/static/version1551965592/frontend/Company/theme/en_US/mage/calendar.css`

see if it loads any css file or gives 404 error if it does then issue is symlink.

2 - Disable static version from admin so magento should not add static version url , follow below path :

> Magento Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer.

Change Sign Static Files setting.

After making changes : remove **pub/static/frontend** folder and **var/view_processed/pub** folder and deploy static content again. ( IMPORTANT, don't delete .htaccess file in pub/static folder be careful )

Hope it will fix the issue.

Comment: Dear ! page layout destroy and also admin page not found 404 .
then how perform this. 
- Disable static version from admin so magento should not add static version url , follow below path :

    Magento Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu edit the file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

To edit this file use `sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf` command

`<Directory /var/www/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
</Directory>`

**To**

`<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>`

After this run command

`sudo service apache2 restart`

IF STILL Structure not right and ADMIN SHOW 404 NOT FOUND, FOLLOW THIS STEP

`

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

rm -rf var/cache/*

rm -rf var/generation/*
```

`